# Bounds on exponential factors $|e^{i(\cosθ+i\sinθ)}| = e^{-\sinθ}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

We often need bound on an exponential $e^{iz}$ on an arc. On $|z| = r$
$$|e^{iz}| = |e^{ ire^{iθ}}|=|e^{ri(\cosθ+i\sinθ)}|=e^{-r\sinθ}$$

I fail to see how we got $e^{-\sinθ}$, please explain if I missed a detail.

Comment: I don't know why you're assuming $|z|=r$.  It doesn't seem to be germane to the problem.  All you have to do to prove the given statement is this: $|e^{iz}|=|e^{i(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))}|=|e^{i\cos(\theta)}e^{ii\sin(\theta)}|=|e^{i\cos(\theta)}||e^{-\sin(\theta)}|=1\cdot |e^{-\sin(\theta)}|=e^{-\sin(\theta)}$

Comment: Wonderful answer, thanks! Yes, the r is something I forgot, but this helped a lot 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $e^{x+y} = e^x e^y$.

If $a,b$ are real, we have $e^{a+ib} = e^a e^{ib}$.

Note that $|e^{ib}| = 1$ for all $b$ hence $|e^{a+ib}| = |e^a| = e^a$.

In your example, we have $a=-\sin \theta$, $b=\cos \theta$.

Comment: This is the rule I was missing, gratitude copper.hat!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $x\in\mathbb{R^+}$:

$$\left|e^{iz}\right|=\left|e^{i re^{ix}}\right|=\left|e^{i(\cos(x)+\sin(x)i)}\right|=\left|e^{i\cos(x)-\sin(x)}\right|=e^{-\Im\left(\cos(x)\right)-\Re\left(\sin(x)\right)}=e^{-\sin(x)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Aren't we forgetting the factor $r$ ?

$
e^{iz}=e^{ire^{i \theta}}=e^{ir(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)} = e^{r(-\sin \theta + i \cos \theta)},
$

so

$
|e^{iz}|=|e^{r(-\sin \theta + i \cos \theta)}|=e^{-r \sin \theta}.
$